# Is there any bigger than 15 inches LCD monitor that works with Multi touch in Raspberry Pi 4 (Chromium browser running in Kiosk mode)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, touch

I have IIyama ProLite T2252MSC-B1 screen which has Projective Capacitive 10 point touch technology. It works like a charm under Windows 10. I was thinking the same will be on Raspberry Pi 4 running latest Raspbian and Chromium browser. But all I got was just single point like mouse emulation. Each time I touch the screen, mouse pointer is visible and moves to the direction when I touched the screen. Comparing to the responsiveness in Windows 10, Raspbian experience is terrible. Touches are not recognized precisely and instead single click sometimes it works like double click, sometimes as a long press (right click). Although in Chromium browser we have support for gestures (ex. Zoom in and out works ok, swipe left right also works ok) but touch (click) is nothing nowhere Windows 10 / mobile phone experience.
I found that this screen is using Weida Hi-Tech digitizer.
Maybe someone knows if there are some other 22 inch monitors that has same level of touch support/experience under Linux / Chromium that is offered in Windows / Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for the solution in google I stumbled on this link:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=179663
I had exactly same issue, looks like some touch events were not recognized / behaving properly.
As a solution you have to add this line to /boot/cmdline.txt file:

```
usbhid.mousepoll=0
```

That tells the kernel to trust the usb hid devices own suggestion as to how often they should be polled.